# android cocos2dx integration with scoreloop

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, scoreloop

I am integrating scoreloop in Android with cocos2dx framework.
 i have download source from [https://github.com/ursine-paw/upSL][1]

[1]: https://github.com/ursine-paw/upSL, where i have put jni_scoreloop.ccp and Scoreloop.h file in classes folder and added using namespace cocos2x in jni_scoreloop.ccp.
but still there is error in submitScore
in jni_scoreloop

```
 void ScoreController::SubmitScore(ScoreController* self, double result, double minor_result, unsigned int level, unsigned int mode, std::map<std::string, std::string>* context==NULL)
```

Anyone have any idea about it then please help me.
and in Scorelopp.h file

```
template argument 3 is invalid
```

and show error